# `mov` a literal to the ES register

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have this portion of code :

```
mov ax, 0x100
mov es, ax
```

but when I try to replace the code above by this :

```
mov es, 0x100
```

nasm tells me that I made an `invalid combination of opcode and operands`. Why ?

Comment: ES doesn't allow immediate values, you have to use a register.

Comment: Whenever you are in doubt, consult the [official instruction set reference](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf). You can see there is no `mov sreg, imm16` instruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because there is no instruction that can move a literal value to the `es` register.

There are different `mov` instructions for different combinations of sources and destinations. There is an instruction to move a literal value to registers, but it can only move it to certain registers, not all of them. That's why you need to put the value in a data register before moving it to a segment register.

Answer (score 1):

There is no literal `es` load instruction.  It was assumed the segment registers have magic cookies.  Those could only be determined at load time or run time.  So the compiler and assembler could not know what literal constant to have ready to load.

However, there is an instruction to load `ES` and an index register:

```
far_ptr   dd       ?
        ...
          LES DI, far_ptr
```

This sets ES and 16-bit register `DI` to the 32-bit value in the memory labeled `far_ptr` which could usefully load a large model pointer.

There are also 32-bit instruction siblings.  Other segment registers and index registers can be set this way.  See [this](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_152.html).